# How to use Android NDK source projects?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android NDK provides a bunch of source projects under $NDK\sources directory. However, I don't see any samples on how to reuse these projects.

The one that I am specifically interested in is $NDK\sources\android\support\Android.mk as it defines iconv library as well as a better implementation of wchar.

I am trying to understand what it takes to incorporate this library in my project. Here are the changes I am thinking in Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(NDK)/sources/android/support/Android.mk

...

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK)/sources/android/support/include

....

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_support
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Is this the right way to use it?

Also, there are two versions of wchar.h - one under support and one under platforms. I am thinking  $(NDK)/sources/android/support/include must come before other includes so that proper wchar.h can be used. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually including $(NDK)/sources/android/support/Android.mk, there's a mechanism for including these - replace the full include line with this:

```
$(call import-module,android/support)
```

I haven't tried using this support library myself, but the same import-module call is widely used to include the cpufeatures library.